# _BaseServer__is_shut_down while running glass framework

Tags: python

i am new to Glass framework i have installed glass server in in my ubuntu system when i run sample test application its return _BaseServer__is_shut_down
error how can i resolve this issue and i already tried different port number but same issue .

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from glass.HTTPServer import test
try:
  print "Use Control-C to exit.  In Windows, use Control-Break."
  test()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  pass
```

when i run this code i got error like

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8080 ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "HTTPServer.py", line 305, in <module>
test()
File "HTTPServer.py", line 300, in test
httpd.serve_forever()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 223, in serve_forever
self.__is_shut_down.clear()
File "HTTPServer.py", line 265, in __getattr__
raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _BaseServer__is_shut_down
```

Comment: No solution solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to fix that issue, but the framework seems really old. I can reditect you to the simplest HTTP server existant, and easy too:

Python 3 (prefered) using [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html):

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000
Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(('', PORT), Handler)
print('serving at port', PORT)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Python 2 using [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html):

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(('', PORT), Handler)
print 'serving at port', PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research inside the framework code I have found the next:

The HTTPServer inside the package is a custom one with a `__getattr__` built-in set that is rising exceptions when an attribute that is not "is_secure" is accessed.

```
# Code from HTTPServer.py
def __getattr__(self, attr):
    if attr == "is_secure":
        return getattr(self.servertype.create_socket, "is_secure", False)
    raise AttributeError(attr)  # This is the buggy statement
```

So in plain, any HTTPServer attribute (except "is_secure") which is accessed will irremediably raise an exception.

I guess you have three options:

1. Fix the test function in order to make it work properly
2. Keep going without using the test function and trying to make that framework work
3. Follow the Tiger-222 solution and stick to the *SimpleHTTPServer*

Comment: i tried different method(without test) but same issue